# Is it possible to have Hibernate ignore the Schema Validation column type mismatch error

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm updating the db that my application is using. The older schema used short a lot for things like id's etc, but the new schema has updated all these to int.
Using a feature toggle for these mappings is next to near impossible with the code base that I have. And I would like to write the code to be able to use both the legacy db and the new one for testing purposes.
Can I switch off the Schema wrong column type exception in Hibernate and just allow short in the db to be mapped to int in the code?

```
SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in 
column [AddressTypeID] in table [dbo.AddressType]; found [smallint 
(Types#SMALLINT)], but expecting [int (Types#INTEGER)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only solution is to switch to turn off `hbm2ddl`

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=none
```

With `none` hibernate skips schema validation